# Convert PDF content to responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am looking into How to programmatically convert PDF content to support responsive html web page,which should be viewable in iOS, android and web browsers as well. Could anyone please provide your insights to take it forward? Also, please provide your suggestions how can it be achieved if any other ways?

Comment: I have used this: http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/
Once you get the HTML, create a web page responsive with empty `section` or `div` and drop in the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free Mozilla's PDF.js library to directly render the PDF file as HTML5 in the browser. Here is a link to the library http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
As you can see the PDF viewer is fully responsive: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html.

Comment: Its not fully responsive, a fully responsive publication would make the PDF readable on a small device a well, like this:

http://devaldi.com/reflow-pdf-example/

Comment: Does this actually turn the pdf content to html5 or it just wraps it in a html5 viewer? When I inspect the demo, the content is html but the examples are just a canvas object.